# Put a file on a SFTP Server

Tags: php, sftp, fopen, wrapper

I'd like to put a file on a STFP server after a Authentification with a Public key (not password).
Manual SFTP in command line works.
First of all, I can't use phpseclib.
'allow_url_fopen' = 1 in my PHP.ini

stream_get_wrappers() gives me: https,ftps,compress.zlib,compress.bzip2,php,file,glob,data,http,ftp,phar,ssh2.shell,ssh2.exec,ssh2.tunnel,ssh2.scp,ssh2.sftp,zip

everything work (in order: ssh2_connect, ssh2_auth_pubkey_file, ssh2_sftp)
but this code doesn't work:

```
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$dest = 'test.txt';
--> $sftpStream = fopen('ssh2.sftp://'.$sftp.$dest, 'w'); <---
PHP Warning:  fopen(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #32test.txt): failed to open stream:
```

Any idea ?

Thank you
S.

Comment: Are you executing this code with the same user that you say it works on commandline? If you are executing this page via a webserver, it gets executed under the same user of the webserver process (tipically www-data in debian/ubuntu or httpd in rhel/centos)

Answer (score 2):

Simple error: you forgot a `/` between `$resource` & `$dest`. So, this will work:

```
$sftpStream = fopen('ssh2.sftp://'.$sftp.'/'.$dest, 'w');
```

.. provided you have write access on the root of your filesystem. You may be required to give the *full* path to the file, aside from executing `cwd` on an ssh-connection I've yet to find a method to put a file in the 'default' dir after connecting.

Answer (score 1):

phpseclib uses fsockopen which allow_url_fopen shouldn't effect.  allow_url_fopen is for things like file() and file_get_contents() - not for fsockopen().